# Llenar ComboBox desde un datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de llenar un ComboBox desde una base de datos en access pero no me trae los datos, y me aparece todo en blanco

```
                conexiones.registration_conexion connect = 
                 new conexiones.registration_conexion();

                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "registration_tool";
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "id";
                this.DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Este es el codigo que tengo en conexiones/registration_conexion

```
public class registration_conexion
    {
        public DataTable connect()
        {
            string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

            DataTable SBTable = new DataTable();

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
                String qry = "SELECT * FROM registration_tool";
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = qry;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                command.Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // close conn after 
                SBTable.Load(reader);
                if (!reader.IsClosed)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }

                return SBTable;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return SBTable;
        }
    }
```

> Solucion

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            conexiones.registration_conexion regconnect = new conexiones.registration_conexion();
            conexiones.registration_conexion RESBTable = new conexiones.registration_conexion();
            DataTable rdvt = RESBTable.regconnect();

            this.Dpo_tool.DataSource = rdvt;

            this.Dpo_tool.DataTextField = "tool_id";
            this.Dpo_tool.DataSource = rdvt;
            this.Dpo_tool.DataBind();
            this.Dpo_tool.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Herramienta", String.Empty));

            this.Dpo_torque.DataSource = rdvt;

            this.Dpo_torque.DataTextField = "torque_max";
            this.Dpo_torque.DataSource = rdvt;
            this.Dpo_torque.DataBind();
            this.Dpo_torque.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Torque", String.Empty));
```

Comment: Cesar, tiene que ser el datatable del metodo de consulta de la bd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta la fuente de datos:

```
this.DropDownList1.DataSource = DataTable;
```

Comment: `DataTable dvt = new DataTable();`
`this.DropDownList1.DataSource = dvt;` se agregue estos pero sigue sin mostrar los datos

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos te dio resultados ?

Comment: Claro, @Pierro, ya funciona al 100%.
Gracias!